# Unable to use XAMPP's Apache server in PhpStorm

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I am configuring PhpStorm according to [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE) guide, but still when I open any php file using the browser links(see the image below) it still opening under `http://localhost:4799/project_name`.

[image]

I was expecting to open it under `http://localhost/project_name`.

What's the problem?

Comment: Please show screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`

Comment: here it is http://imgur.com/Myrw3vv

Comment: Did you fill the "Deployment path" field on "Mappings" tab? I think you will see a warning there.

Comment: Yes i am getting a warning. "Deployment path is not specified". I updated Mappings pls take a look http://imgur.com/QEkA1SR

Comment: So .. it should be working now, right? Unless you screw up this somehow. What URL it opens now when you use `Open in Browser` with your current settings?

Comment: still opening with http://localhost:4799/project_name

Comment: You still must have done something wrong (I guess) as it definitely works (just tested locally on brand new project). I suggest 1) Delete that deployment entry; save settings; open them again; create deployment entry again 2) Do not use just `css` -- use `/css/` (or maybe leave it as `/` for now). 3) If still nothing -- consider creating brand new project (with single file) and test it there

Comment: I created a new project and now everything is working as expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same setup (xampp with PHPStorm). Make sure you have the [project deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/deployment.html?origin=old_help) set correctly.  Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment.  The web server root URL should be http://localhost/project_name and it should be selected as the default server for the project.

Comment: Try checking your [run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html?origin=old_help) at Run > Edit Configurations. Sounds like those may not be set correctly.

Comment: @thanks for reply but the issue is resolved with the help of LazyOne